# How can I create a PopUp menu to adjust the light setting in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, popupmenu

Can I create a PopUp menu to change or modify my light property in OpenGL using SDL?

I am trying to use `glutCreateMenu();`:

```
void mydisplay()
{
    //glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLfloat tp_ambient[] = { 0.05,0.05,0.05,1 };
    GLfloat tp_diffuse[] = { 0.7,0.3,1,1 };
    GLfloat tp_specular[] = { 0.6,0.6,0.6,1 };
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT, tp_ambient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_DIFFUSE, tp_diffuse);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, tp_specular);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -0.6f);
    GLUquadricObj *quadric = gluNewQuadric();
    gluSphere(quadric, 0.1, 16, 16);
    gluDeleteQuadric(quadric);

    glPopMatrix();
    /*
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -0.1f);*/

    glutCreateMenu(ProcessMenu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("position change", 0);
    glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);

}
void ProcessMenu(int value) {
    if (value == 0) {
        GLfloat ambient[] = { 0.1,0.1,0.1,1 };
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

But I get this error:

> Error C2065   'ProcessMenu': undeclared identifier

What should I set up?
Am I using the correct way to build a PopUp menu?
If it is useful to view all my coding, please have a look on my [previous, solved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49705570/how-should-i-create-a-new-object-in-this-room-opengl).

Comment: You need to move `void ProcessMenu(int value) { ... }` before where it is used (or forward declare it).

Comment: @RichardCritten Ic, error C2065 solved

Comment: @Rabbid76 openGL

Comment: I am sorry that being stupid in front of coding. 
Here I want to try glutCreateMenu(); in OpenGL @Rabbid76

Comment: If you are new, you could consider learning modern OpenGL instead of the ~20 years old version you're using.

Comment: I would suggest you to look at dear imgui.